# How to get an element from the DOM when using Factory Pattern in Angular

Tags: angular, dom, state, getelementbyid, factory-pattern

I cannot get a specific element from the DOM using getElementById or getElementsByClassName. I'm implementing a factory pattern in Angular by using `ComponentFactoryResolver` (see the example in Stackblitz below).

When I create the first pizza and I want to select an element, it is giving me null or an empty HTMLCollection. But when I select a topping and create a new pizza now I can see the element in the console.

I setup two divs in the pizza.component.html (one for an `id` and another one for a `class`- lines 5 and 6).

I am printing out in the pizza.component.ts file the `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` using the ngOnInit method (lines 15 and 16).

Is there a way to create a pizza and access these elements without waiting for the selection of the topping and the creation on a new pizza? In other words, to get access to the state of the component?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pizza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpizza%2Fpizza.component.ts)

Comment: Unless, you select any topping after creating the pizza, the for loop "toppings" in PizzaComponent doesn't have any value, and hence, it doesn't render whatever elements are inside that for loop. That is the expected behavior.

Now, can you be specific about what you want to achieve? I mean yes you can access the elements inside the "toppings" for loop, but not until "toppings" array has value.

Comment: @SumitVekariya I'm trying to get an element to draw a visjs diagram after fetching the data from the DB. Because I want to draw different diagrams in the same page I am using the factory pattern but I need to get the ```id``` of a specific element to draw it. I already insert one topping when I create an instance of the pizza (```choices.component.ts```)  to see if I can get the element but not, I couldn't. I need to get access to the DOM immediately after I create an instance of the component. Thanks!